# Calculate the arclength, curve length of a cubic bezier curve. Why is not working?

Tags: javascript, math, bezier

I'm calculating the arclength (length of a cubic bezier curve) with this algorithm

```
    function getArcLength(path) {

        var STEPS = 1000; // > precision
        var t = 1 / STEPS;
        var aX=0;
        var aY=0;
        var bX=0, bY=0;
        var dX=0, dY=0;
        var dS = 0;
        var sumArc = 0;
        var j = 0;

        for (var i=0; i<STEPS; j = j + t) {
            aX = bezierPoint(j, path[0], path[2], path[4], path[6]);
            aY = bezierPoint(j, path[1], path[3], path[5], path[7]);
            dX = aX - bX;
            dY = aY - bY;
            // deltaS. Pitagora
            dS = Math.sqrt((dX * dX) + (dY * dY));
            sumArc = sumArc + dS;
            bX = aX;
            bY = aY;
            i++;
        }

        return sumArc;
    }
```

But what I get is something like 915. But the curve is 480 and no more. (I know for sure this because the curve is almost a line)
The path array has this values:
498 51 500 52 500 53 500 530

The bezierPoint function is:

```
        function bezierPoint(t, o1, c1, c2, e1) {
        var C1 = (e1 - (3.0 * c2) + (3.0 * c1) - o1);
        var C2 = ((3.0 * c2) - (6.0 * c1) + (3.0 * o1));
        var C3 = ((3.0 * c1) - (3.0 * o1));
        var C4 = (o1);

        return ((C1*t*t*t) + (C2*t*t) + (C3*t) + C4)
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's important to note here that `1/STEPS` is a floating-point division in JavaScript.  In certain other languages this is an integer division and may cause incorrect results.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006480/cubic-bezier-curve-arc-length-is-always-zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `bX` and `bY` are initialized to 0, the first segment when i = 0 measures the distance from the origin to the start of the path.  This adds an extra sqrt(498^2+51^2) to the length.  If you initialize `bX = path[0]` and `bY = path[1]`, I think it will work.