# Trying to find length of a bezier curve with 4 points

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, bezier

I've found about a 1000 answers to this question, but none of them I can use, because I'm using 4 control points with my curves.

That said, I stumbled on this guy [here](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/curves/cbezarclen.html):

```
double BezierArcLength(point2d p1, point2d p2, point2d p3, point2d p4)
{
    point2d k1, k2, k3, k4;

    k1 = -p1 + 3*(p2 - p3) + p4;
    k2 = 3*(p1 + p3) - 6*p2;
    k3 = 3*(p2 - p1);
    k4 = p1;

    q1 = 9.0*(sqr(k1.x) + sqr(k1.y));
    q2 = 12.0*(k1.x*k2.x + k1.y*k2.y);
    q3 = 3.0*(k1.x*k3.x + k1.y*k3.y) + 4.0*(sqr(k2.x) + sqr(k2.y));
    q4 = 4.0*(k2.x*k3.x + k2.y*k3.y);
    q5 = sqr(k3.x) + sqr(k3.y);

    double result = Simpson(balf, 0, 1, 1024, 0.001);
    return result;
}
```

It looks like it'd be the perfect solution, but that beginning part is utterly confusing to me:

```
k1 = -p1 + 3*(p2 - p3) + p4;
k2 = 3*(p1 + p3) - 6*p2;
k3 = 3*(p2 - p1);
k4 = p1;
```

How on earth am I supposed to do operations like add, subtract and multiply on 2-dimensional objects (I presume point2d is an object structure like `{x: 0, y: 0}`)? I feel idiotic, but this is the only thing keeping me from actually implementing this monstrosity.

FWIW, I'm using this equation to normalize an entity's speed when traversing the curve in a game. If you know a better way of doing this altogether, I'm all ears.

Comment: Question: How on earth am I supposed to do operations like add, subtract and multiply on 2-dimensional objects? Answer: You do them on one coordinate (x or y) at a time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Here’s how to traverse your cubic bezier curve at uniform speed**

There isn't one simple formula for getting even length segments along a cubic bezier curve (meaning even arc-length segments).  What's involved is calculating many points along the curve and then using interpolation to “nudge” each point into being roughly equidistant.

I can get you nearly there without your having to get a PH.D in Mathematics.

Start by using the common formula to calculate x/y points on the curve from t=0 to t=1 where t=0 represents the startpoint of the curve and t=1 represents the endpoint of the curve.  This is the common formula:

```
// calc the x/y point at t interval
// t=0 at startPt, t=1 at endPt
var x=CubicN(t,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
var y=CubicN(t,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);

// cubic helper formula at t interval
function CubicN(t, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = t * t;
    var t3 = t2 * t;
    return a + (-a * 3 + t * (3 * a - a * t)) * t
    + (3 * b + t * (-6 * b + b * 3 * t)) * t
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * t) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

If you calculate enough intervals, say 100 intervals  (t += .01 each loop) then you will get a very good approximation of the curve.

That means if you connect the 100 points with lines, the result would look very much like a cubic bezier curve.

But you're not done!

**The series of x/y points calculated above are not uniform in arc-distance from each other.**

Some neighboring points are close together and some neighboring points are farther apart.

To calculate evenly distributed points:

1. Connect all the points with lines (creating a polyline).
2. Calculate the total distance (T) of that polyline.
3. Divide (T) by the number of uniform segments you desire, getting the uniform segment length (SL)
4. Finally, walk the polyline from start to end, calculating each point that is (SL) distance from the previous point.

Result: you can use these equidistant points to traverse your curve.

Additional Refinement:  This should result in a visually smooth movement along your Bezier path.  But if you desire even more smoothness, just calculate more than 100 points--more points == more smoothness.

Comment: Just to try and attempt to expand point 4 for anyone else who (like me) struggles with it.

In my instance I had taken 10 samples of my various intervals (represented as "t", in the above example). Once i got the "SL", instead of dividing each sample by 10, I divided it by the result of it's interval's average length. The equation is something like `single sample from interval (t) / (length of interval / average length of all intervals)`. 

You may also need to adjust your power of tens, but I'm not sure if that's for certain or just in my case.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-dimensional object, or a Point2D, is simply a Vector, and [Vector Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) is well-defined in mathematics.  For example:

```
          k*(x,y) = (k*x, k*y)
           -(x,y) = (-1)*(x,y)
(x1,y1) + (x2,y2) = (x1+x2, y1+y2)
```

Those are all the formulas you need to calculate `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, and `k4`

Comment: That's not what TS has asked.

Comment: Well, it was part of his question, "How on earth am I supposed to do operations like add, subtract and multiply on 2-dimensional objects?"

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the browser method `getTotalLength()` you might use this helper based on Snap.svg's [`bezlen()`](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/dist/snap.svg.js#L5786) function to approximate a cubic bézier length.

```js
/**
 * Based on snap.svg bezlen() function
 * https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/dist/snap.svg.js#L5786
 */
function cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 1) {
  if (t === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  const base3 = (t, p1, p2, p3, p4) => {
    let t1 = -3 * p1 + 9 * p2 - 9 * p3 + 3 * p4,
      t2 = t * t1 + 6 * p1 - 12 * p2 + 6 * p3;
    return t * t2 - 3 * p1 + 3 * p2;
  };
  t = t > 1 ? 1 : t < 0 ? 0 : t;
  let t2 = t / 2;
  let Tvalues =  [-.1252, .1252, -.3678, .3678, -.5873, .5873, -.7699, .7699, -.9041, .9041, -.9816, .9816];
  let Cvalues = [0.2491, 0.2491, 0.2335, 0.2335, 0.2032, 0.2032, 0.1601, 0.1601, 0.1069, 0.1069, 0.0472, 0.0472];
  
  
  let n = Tvalues.length;
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let ct = t2 * Tvalues[i] + t2,
      xbase = base3(ct, p0.x, cp1.x, cp2.x, p.x),
      ybase = base3(ct, p0.y, cp1.y, cp2.y, p.y),
      comb = xbase * xbase + ybase * ybase;
    sum += Cvalues[i] * Math.sqrt(comb);
  }
  return t2 * sum;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 300  300 " style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <path id="path" d="" stroke="#999" fill="none" stroke-width="1%"></path>
</svg>

<script>  
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{

//example points
let p0 = { x: 250, y: 40 },
  cp1 = { x: 0, y: 240 },
  cp2 = { x: 0, y: 250 },
  p = { x: 260, y: 240 };

// render example to svg
path.setAttribute(
  "d",
  `M${p0.x} ${p0.y} C ${cp1.x} ${cp1.y} ${cp2.x} ${cp2.y}  ${p.x} ${p.y}`
);

// native getTotalLength()
let t0 = performance.now();
let length = path.getTotalLength();
let end0 = +(performance.now() - t0).toFixed(5) + " ms";

// calculated with helper
let t1 = performance.now();
let lengthCalc = cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, 1);
let end1 = +(performance.now() - t1).toFixed(5) + " ms";

console.log('native: ', length, end0, 'calculated: ', lengthCalc, end1)
console.log("diff:", length - lengthCalc)
})
</script>
```

Deviation from `getTotalLength()` : -0.015894306215841425
(Measured in blink/chromium)

This helper is based on Legendre-Gauss quadrature evalutation using a n=12 lookup.
See also "Primer on Bezier Curves" [§24 Arc length](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arclength).

You can also improve accuracy by using a more precise abscissae/weight [lookup array](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/legendre-gauss.html) like n=24

```js
/**
 * Based on snap.svg bezlen() function
 * https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/dist/snap.svg.js#L5786
 */
function cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 1) {
  if (t === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  const base3 = (t, p1, p2, p3, p4) => {
    let t1 = -3 * p1 + 9 * p2 - 9 * p3 + 3 * p4,
      t2 = t * t1 + 6 * p1 - 12 * p2 + 6 * p3;
    return t * t2 - 3 * p1 + 3 * p2;
  };
  t = t > 1 ? 1 : t < 0 ? 0 : t;
  let t2 = t / 2;
  let Tvalues =  [
        -0.0640568928626056260850430826247450385909,
        0.0640568928626056260850430826247450385909,
        -0.1911188674736163091586398207570696318404,
        0.1911188674736163091586398207570696318404,
        -0.3150426796961633743867932913198102407864,
        0.3150426796961633743867932913198102407864,
        -0.4337935076260451384870842319133497124524,
        0.4337935076260451384870842319133497124524,
        -0.5454214713888395356583756172183723700107,
        0.5454214713888395356583756172183723700107,
        -0.6480936519369755692524957869107476266696,
        0.6480936519369755692524957869107476266696,
        -0.7401241915785543642438281030999784255232,
        0.7401241915785543642438281030999784255232,
        -0.8200019859739029219539498726697452080761,
        0.8200019859739029219539498726697452080761,
        -0.8864155270044010342131543419821967550873,
        0.8864155270044010342131543419821967550873,
        -0.9382745520027327585236490017087214496548,
        0.9382745520027327585236490017087214496548,
        -0.9747285559713094981983919930081690617411,
        0.9747285559713094981983919930081690617411,
        -0.9951872199970213601799974097007368118745,
        0.9951872199970213601799974097007368118745
    ];
  let Cvalues = [
        0.1279381953467521569740561652246953718517,
        0.1279381953467521569740561652246953718517,
        0.1258374563468282961213753825111836887264,
        0.1258374563468282961213753825111836887264,
        0.1216704729278033912044631534762624256070,
        0.1216704729278033912044631534762624256070,
        0.1155056680537256013533444839067835598622,
        0.1155056680537256013533444839067835598622,
        0.1074442701159656347825773424466062227946,
        0.1074442701159656347825773424466062227946,
        0.0976186521041138882698806644642471544279,
        0.0976186521041138882698806644642471544279,
        0.0861901615319532759171852029837426671850,
        0.0861901615319532759171852029837426671850,
        0.0733464814110803057340336152531165181193,
        0.0733464814110803057340336152531165181193,
        0.0592985849154367807463677585001085845412,
        0.0592985849154367807463677585001085845412,
        0.0442774388174198061686027482113382288593,
        0.0442774388174198061686027482113382288593,
        0.0285313886289336631813078159518782864491,
        0.0285313886289336631813078159518782864491,
        0.0123412297999871995468056670700372915759,
        0.0123412297999871995468056670700372915759
    ];
  
  
  let n = Tvalues.length;
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let ct = t2 * Tvalues[i] + t2,
      xbase = base3(ct, p0.x, cp1.x, cp2.x, p.x),
      ybase = base3(ct, p0.y, cp1.y, cp2.y, p.y),
      comb = xbase * xbase + ybase * ybase;
    sum += Cvalues[i] * Math.sqrt(comb);
  }
  return t2 * sum;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 300  300 " style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <path id="path" d="" stroke="#999" fill="none" stroke-width="1%"></path>
</svg>

<script>  
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e=>{

//example points
let p0 = { x: 250, y: 40 },
  cp1 = { x: 0, y: 240 },
  cp2 = { x: 0, y: 250 },
  p = { x: 260, y: 240 };

// render example to svg
path.setAttribute(
  "d",
  `M${p0.x} ${p0.y} C ${cp1.x} ${cp1.y} ${cp2.x} ${cp2.y}  ${p.x} ${p.y}`
);

// native getTotalLength()
let t0 = performance.now();
let length = path.getTotalLength();
let end0 = +(performance.now() - t0).toFixed(5) + " ms";

// calculated with helper
let t1 = performance.now();
let lengthCalc = cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, 1);
let end1 = +(performance.now() - t1).toFixed(5) + " ms";

console.log('native: ', length, end0, 'calculated: ', lengthCalc, end1)
console.log("diff:", length - lengthCalc)
})
</script>
```

Deviation from `getTotalLength()` : 0.0005884069474291209
(Measured in blink/chromium)

#### Emulate [`pointAtLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength)

The helper function can also approximate the length of a curve at a specific `t` value.

Unfortunately, we can't translate length at t values to the actual segment path length – in other words: length at t=0.25 doesn't equal 1/4 of the total path length (t=1).

But we can get an acceptable approximation by creating a (length at `t`) lookup to interpolate between `t` values:

```js
/**
 * calculate point at length values
 * based on interpolated length at t values
 */
function getPointAtLengthLookup(lengthLookup, length) {
  let foundT = false;
  let pt;
  let {
    points,
    lengths
  } = lengthLookup;
  let [p0, cp1, cp2, p] = [points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3]];
  let tStep = 1 / (lengths.length - 1);
  let lengthTotal = lengths[lengths.length - 1];

  // first point
  if (length === 0) {
    return p0;
  }

  // last point
  if (length.toFixed(3) === lengthTotal.toFixed(3)) {
    return p;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < lengths.length && !foundT; i++) {
    let lengthAtT = lengths[i];
    let lengthAtTPrev = i > 0 ? lengths[i - 1] : lengths[i];
    // found length at t range
    if (lengthAtT > length) {
      let t = tStep * i;
      // length between previous and current t
      let tSegLength = lengthAtT - lengthAtTPrev;
      // difference between length at t and exact length
      let diffLength = lengthAtT - length;
      // ratio between segment length and difference
      let tScale = (1 / tSegLength) * diffLength;
      let newT = t - tStep * tScale;

      foundT = true;
      pt = getPointAtCubicSegmentT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, newT);
    }
  }
  return pt;
}


/**
 * create length at t lookup
 */
function getPathLengthLookup(points, tDivisions = 10) {
  let lengthLookup = {
    points: points,
    lengths: [],
    diviations: []
  };
  let pL = points.length;
  let p0 = points[0],
    cp1 = points[1],
    cp2,
    p = points[pL - 1];
  if (points.length === 4) {
    cp2 = points[2];
  }
  let lengthCalc = cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, 1);

  for (let i = 0; i < tDivisions; i++) {
    let t = (1 / tDivisions) * i;
    let len = cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t);
    lengthLookup.lengths.push(len);
  }

  lengthLookup.lengths.push(lengthCalc);
  lengthLookup.diviations.push(0);
  return lengthLookup;
}

/**
 * Based on snap.svg bezlen() function
 * https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/dist/snap.svg.js#L5786
 */
function cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 1) {
  if (t === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  const base3 = (t, p1, p2, p3, p4) => {
    let t1 = -3 * p1 + 9 * p2 - 9 * p3 + 3 * p4,
      t2 = t * t1 + 6 * p1 - 12 * p2 + 6 * p3;
    return t * t2 - 3 * p1 + 3 * p2;
  };
  t = t > 1 ? 1 : t < 0 ? 0 : t;
  let t2 = t / 2;
  let Tvalues = [-0.1252,
    0.1252, -0.3678,
    0.3678, -0.5873,
    0.5873, -0.7699,
    0.7699, -0.9041,
    0.9041, -0.9816,
    0.9816
  ];
  let Cvalues = [
    0.2491,
    0.2491,
    0.2335,
    0.2335,
    0.2032,
    0.2032,
    0.1601,
    0.1601,
    0.1069,
    0.1069,
    0.0472,
    0.0472
  ];


  let n = Tvalues.length;
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let ct = t2 * Tvalues[i] + t2,
      xbase = base3(ct, p0.x, cp1.x, cp2.x, p.x),
      ybase = base3(ct, p0.y, cp1.y, cp2.y, p.y),
      comb = xbase * xbase + ybase * ybase;
    sum += Cvalues[i] * Math.sqrt(comb);
  }
  return t2 * sum;
}

function quadraticBezierLength(p0, cp1, p, t = 1) {
  if (t === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  const interpolate = (p1, p2, t) => {
    let pt = {
      x: (p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x,
      y: (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y
    };
    return pt;
  };
  const getLineLength = (p1, p2) => {
    return Math.sqrt(
      (p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)
    );
  };

  // is flat/linear
  let l1 = getLineLength(p0, cp1) + getLineLength(cp1, p);
  let l2 = getLineLength(p0, p);
  if (l1 === l2) {
    let m1 = interpolate(p0, cp1, t);
    let m2 = interpolate(cp1, p, t);
    p = interpolate(m1, m2, t);
    let lengthL;
    lengthL = Math.sqrt(
      (p.x - p0.x) * (p.x - p0.x) + (p.y - p0.y) * (p.y - p0.y)
    );
    return lengthL;
  }

  let a, b, c, d, e, e1, d1, v1x, v1y;

  v1x = cp1.x * 2;
  v1y = cp1.y * 2;
  d = p0.x - v1x + p.x;
  d1 = p0.y - v1y + p.y;
  e = v1x - 2 * p0.x;
  e1 = v1y - 2 * p0.y;
  a = 4 * (d * d + d1 * d1);
  b = 4 * (d * e + d1 * e1);
  c = e * e + e1 * e1;

  const bt = b / (2 * a),
    ct = c / a,
    ut = t + bt,
    k = ct - bt ** 2;

  return (
    (Math.sqrt(a) / 2) *
    (ut * Math.sqrt(ut ** 2 + k) -
      bt * Math.sqrt(bt ** 2 + k) +
      k *
      Math.log((ut + Math.sqrt(ut ** 2 + k)) / (bt + Math.sqrt(bt ** 2 + k))))
  );
}

function getLineLength(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt(
    (p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)
  );
}

/**
 * Linear  interpolation (LERP) helper
 */
function interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, t = 0.5) {
  //t: 0.5 - point in the middle
  if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
    p1.x = p1[0];
    p1.y = p1[1];
  }
  if (Array.isArray(p2)) {
    p2.x = p2[0];
    p2.y = p2[1];
  }
  let [x, y] = [(p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x, (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y];
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

/**
 * calculate single points on segments
 */
function getPointAtCubicSegmentT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 ** 3 * p0.x +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.x +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.x +
      t ** 3 * p.x,
    y: t1 ** 3 * p0.y +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.y +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.y +
      t ** 3 * p.y
  };
}



function renderPoint(
  svg,
  coords,
  fill = "red",
  r = "2",
  opacity = "1",
  id = "",
  className = ""
) {
  //console.log(coords);
  if (Array.isArray(coords)) {
    coords = {
      x: coords[0],
      y: coords[1]
    };
  }

  let marker = `<circle class="${className}" opacity="${opacity}" id="${id}" cx="${coords.x}" cy="${coords.y}" r="${r}" fill="${fill}">
  <title>${coords.x} ${coords.y}</title></circle>`;
  svg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", marker);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 300  300 " style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <path id="path" d="" stroke="#999" fill="none" stroke-width="1%"></path>
  <g id="segs"></g>
</svg>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    let p0 = {
        x: 150,
        y: 50
      },
      cp1 = {
        x: 400,
        y: 100
      },
      cp2 = {
        x: -200,
        y: 200
      },
      p = {
        x: 150,
        y: 250
      };

    path.setAttribute(
      "d",
      `M${p0.x} ${p0.y} C ${cp1.x} ${cp1.y} ${cp2.x} ${cp2.y}  ${p.x} ${p.y}`
    );


    let length = path.getTotalLength();
    let lengthCalc = cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, 1);


    /**
     * get lookup
     */
    let tDivision = 10;
    let lengthLookup = getPathLengthLookup([p0, cp1, cp2, p], tDivision);
    let {
      points,
      lengths
    } = lengthLookup;

    // points on path
    let steps = 10;
    let ptsN = [];
    let ptsC = [];

    //calculate points with native `getPointAtLength()`
    for (let i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
      //native
      let pt0 = path.getPointAtLength((lengthCalc / steps) * i);
      renderPoint(segs, pt0, "black", "1.2%");

      // approximated
      let totalLength = lengths[lengths.length - 1];
      let pt = getPointAtLengthLookup(lengthLookup, (totalLength / steps) * i);
      renderPoint(segs, pt, "red", "1.2%");

    }
  })
</script>
```

(Black circles: native point at length; red circles: interpolated)
As you can see, 10 steps (0, 0.1 – 0.9, 1) are not very accurate.

We can improve accuracy by increasing the number of lengths at t calculations in the search, e.g. by storing lengths for t 1/36.
This will of course take more time to get a better search, which will affect performance. But this disadvantage balances out when we have to calculate many points.

```js
/**
 * calculate point at length values
 * based on interpolated length at t values
 */
function getPointAtLengthLookup(lengthLookup, length) {
  let foundT = false;
  let pt;
  let {
    points,
    lengths
  } = lengthLookup;
  let [p0, cp1, cp2, p] = [points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3]];
  let tStep = 1 / (lengths.length - 1);
  let lengthTotal = lengths[lengths.length - 1];

  // first point
  if (length === 0) {
    return p0;
  }

  // last point
  if (length.toFixed(3) === lengthTotal.toFixed(3)) {
    return p;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < lengths.length && !foundT; i++) {
    let lengthAtT = lengths[i];
    let lengthAtTPrev = i > 0 ? lengths[i - 1] : lengths[i];
    // found length at t range
    if (lengthAtT > length) {
      let t = tStep * i;
      // length between previous and current t
      let tSegLength = lengthAtT - lengthAtTPrev;
      // difference between length at t and exact length
      let diffLength = lengthAtT - length;
      // ratio between segment length and difference
      let tScale = (1 / tSegLength) * diffLength;
      let newT = t - tStep * tScale;

      foundT = true;
      pt = getPointAtCubicSegmentT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, newT);
    }
  }
  return pt;
}


/**
 * create length at t lookup
 */
function getPathLengthLookup(points, tDivisions = 10) {
  let lengthLookup = {
    points: points,
    lengths: [],
    diviations: []
  };
  let pL = points.length;
  let p0 = points[0],
    cp1 = points[1],
    cp2,
    p = points[pL - 1];
  if (points.length === 4) {
    cp2 = points[2];
  }
  let lengthCalc = cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, 1);

  for (let i = 0; i < tDivisions; i++) {
    let t = (1 / tDivisions) * i;
    let len = cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t);
    lengthLookup.lengths.push(len);
  }

  lengthLookup.lengths.push(lengthCalc);
  lengthLookup.diviations.push(0);
  return lengthLookup;
}

/**
 * Based on snap.svg bezlen() function
 * https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/dist/snap.svg.js#L5786
 */
function cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 1) {
  if (t === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  const base3 = (t, p1, p2, p3, p4) => {
    let t1 = -3 * p1 + 9 * p2 - 9 * p3 + 3 * p4,
      t2 = t * t1 + 6 * p1 - 12 * p2 + 6 * p3;
    return t * t2 - 3 * p1 + 3 * p2;
  };
  t = t > 1 ? 1 : t < 0 ? 0 : t;
  let t2 = t / 2;
  let Tvalues = [-0.1252,
    0.1252, -0.3678,
    0.3678, -0.5873,
    0.5873, -0.7699,
    0.7699, -0.9041,
    0.9041, -0.9816,
    0.9816
  ];
  let Cvalues = [
    0.2491,
    0.2491,
    0.2335,
    0.2335,
    0.2032,
    0.2032,
    0.1601,
    0.1601,
    0.1069,
    0.1069,
    0.0472,
    0.0472
  ];


  let n = Tvalues.length;
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let ct = t2 * Tvalues[i] + t2,
      xbase = base3(ct, p0.x, cp1.x, cp2.x, p.x),
      ybase = base3(ct, p0.y, cp1.y, cp2.y, p.y),
      comb = xbase * xbase + ybase * ybase;
    sum += Cvalues[i] * Math.sqrt(comb);
  }
  return t2 * sum;
}

function quadraticBezierLength(p0, cp1, p, t = 1) {
  if (t === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  const interpolate = (p1, p2, t) => {
    let pt = {
      x: (p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x,
      y: (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y
    };
    return pt;
  };
  const getLineLength = (p1, p2) => {
    return Math.sqrt(
      (p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)
    );
  };

  // is flat/linear
  let l1 = getLineLength(p0, cp1) + getLineLength(cp1, p);
  let l2 = getLineLength(p0, p);
  if (l1 === l2) {
    let m1 = interpolate(p0, cp1, t);
    let m2 = interpolate(cp1, p, t);
    p = interpolate(m1, m2, t);
    let lengthL;
    lengthL = Math.sqrt(
      (p.x - p0.x) * (p.x - p0.x) + (p.y - p0.y) * (p.y - p0.y)
    );
    return lengthL;
  }

  let a, b, c, d, e, e1, d1, v1x, v1y;

  v1x = cp1.x * 2;
  v1y = cp1.y * 2;
  d = p0.x - v1x + p.x;
  d1 = p0.y - v1y + p.y;
  e = v1x - 2 * p0.x;
  e1 = v1y - 2 * p0.y;
  a = 4 * (d * d + d1 * d1);
  b = 4 * (d * e + d1 * e1);
  c = e * e + e1 * e1;

  const bt = b / (2 * a),
    ct = c / a,
    ut = t + bt,
    k = ct - bt ** 2;

  return (
    (Math.sqrt(a) / 2) *
    (ut * Math.sqrt(ut ** 2 + k) -
      bt * Math.sqrt(bt ** 2 + k) +
      k *
      Math.log((ut + Math.sqrt(ut ** 2 + k)) / (bt + Math.sqrt(bt ** 2 + k))))
  );
}

function getLineLength(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt(
    (p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)
  );
}

/**
 * Linear  interpolation (LERP) helper
 */
function interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, t = 0.5) {
  //t: 0.5 - point in the middle
  if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
    p1.x = p1[0];
    p1.y = p1[1];
  }
  if (Array.isArray(p2)) {
    p2.x = p2[0];
    p2.y = p2[1];
  }
  let [x, y] = [(p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x, (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y];
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

/**
 * calculate single points on segments
 */
function getPointAtCubicSegmentT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 ** 3 * p0.x +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.x +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.x +
      t ** 3 * p.x,
    y: t1 ** 3 * p0.y +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.y +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.y +
      t ** 3 * p.y
  };
}



function renderPoint(
  svg,
  coords,
  fill = "red",
  r = "2",
  opacity = "1",
  id = "",
  className = ""
) {
  //console.log(coords);
  if (Array.isArray(coords)) {
    coords = {
      x: coords[0],
      y: coords[1]
    };
  }

  let marker = `<circle class="${className}" opacity="${opacity}" id="${id}" cx="${coords.x}" cy="${coords.y}" r="${r}" fill="${fill}">
  <title>${coords.x} ${coords.y}</title></circle>`;
  svg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", marker);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>t division <span id="spanT"></span><input class="inputs" id="inpT" type="range" value="36" min="5" max="72" step="1"></label>
  <label>points on path <span id="spanPoints"></span><input class="inputs" id="inpPoints" type="range" value="10" min="5" max="500" step="1"></label>
</p>

<p><strong>Performance:</strong> native: <span id="perfN"></span> calculated:<span id="perfC"></span></p>


<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 300  300 " style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <path id="path" d="" stroke="#999" fill="none" stroke-width="1%"></path>
  <g id="segs"></g>
</svg>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    let p0 = {
        x: 150,
        y: 50
      },
      cp1 = {
        x: 400,
        y: 100
      },
      cp2 = {
        x: -200,
        y: 200
      },
      p = {
        x: 150,
        y: 250
      };
    
    path.setAttribute(
      "d",
      `M${p0.x} ${p0.y} C ${cp1.x} ${cp1.y} ${cp2.x} ${cp2.y}  ${p.x} ${p.y}`
    );
    let length = path.getTotalLength();
    let lengthCalc = cubicBezierLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, 1);
    
    
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs')
    inputs.forEach(input=>{
      input.addEventListener('input', e=>{
         renderPointsatLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p)
      });
    })

    renderPointsatLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p)
    function renderPointsatLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p) {
      let tDivision = +inpT.value;
      spanT.textContent = tDivision
      segs.innerHTML = '';
      /**
       * get lookup
       */
      let lengthLookup = getPathLengthLookup([p0, cp1, cp2, p], tDivision);
      let {
        points,
        lengths
      } = lengthLookup;
      
      let steps = +inpPoints.value;
      spanPoints.textContent = steps;
      let ptsN = [];
      let ptsC = [];
      
      //calculate points with native `getPointAtLength()`
      let t0 = performance.now();
      for (let i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
        let pt = path.getPointAtLength((lengthCalc / steps) * i);
        ptsN.push(pt);
      }
      let end0 = +(performance.now() - t0).toFixed(8) + " ms";
      perfN.textContent = end0

      
      
      //calculate points with helper
      let t1 = performance.now();
      for (let i = 0; i <= steps; i++) {
        let totalLength = lengths[lengths.length - 1];
        let pt = getPointAtLengthLookup(lengthLookup, (totalLength / steps) * i);
        ptsC.push(pt);
      }
      let end1 = +(performance.now() - t1).toFixed(8) + " ms";
      perfC.textContent = end1

      //console.log('native: ', end0, 'calculated: ', end1)
      //render points
      ptsN.forEach(pt => {
        renderPoint(segs, pt, "black", "1.2%");
      })
      ptsC.forEach(pt => {
        renderPoint(segs, pt, "red", "1.2%");
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```

#### Performance vs. Accuracy

In fact, a sloppy but fast approximation might be a better option compared to a more accurate but significantly more expensive calculation.
The overly simplified benchmarks generated are by no means representative.
However, calculating a lot of (e.g >50) "on path" points at a given length via `getPointAtLength()` are quite expensive –
More than 10 000 can even noticeable slow down the page rendering.

#### Related posts

["Bezier curve arc lengths"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600441/bezier-curve-arc-lengths)
["Calculate the arclength, curve length of a cubic bezier curve. Why is not working?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489520/calculate-the-arclength-curve-length-of-a-cubic-bezier-curve-why-is-not-workin)