# Bezier curve arc lengths

Tags: math, geometry, bezier

I have some code that calculates the length of bezier curves.  I'm trying to write unit tests for it.  But other than the trivial cases (straight line beziers) I don't know any actual correct values for the lengths.  I've looked online and been unable to find any.

Does someone have this info?  I'm looking for a link to a table with a few rows containing four bezier control points and then a length, or possibly create a couple of beziers in a drawing program that calculates the length (I've tried using blender and inkscape to get this info and they're quite complicated).

**Solution.**  Download pomax's bezier javascript code from [here](https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs/blob/gh-pages/lib/bezier.js) and then open this html in a web browser:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="bezier.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
curve = new Bezier([4.0, 0.0,  4.0, 
                    4.0, 0.0,  12.0,
                   16.0, 0.0,  12.0,
                   16.0, 0.0,  4.0]);

document.write(curve.length());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want *actual* arc lengths to test against, implement https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs/blob/gh-pages/lib/bezier.js#L602-604 - this will get you arbitrarily accurate numbers.

Comment: modern browsers already have an arc length calculator as part of the SVG spec. see my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38626906/720204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want *actual* arc lengths to test against, you'll have to implement your own [bezier length code](http://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/#length) by doing something [like this](https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs/blob/4e767299184ab4079dc8d7c970020103db14f431/src/utils.js#L265-L276), computing arbitrarily accurate numbers based on calculating the [Legendre-Gauss quadrature](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/legendre-gauss.html) (you don't have to understand how it works, although the video link shows you that it's actually ridiculously simple. Consequently, implementing it is thankfully really easy).

Another option is to rely on something like [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=length+of+%28100*%281-t%29%5E3%2B10*3*%281-t%29%5E2*t%2B200*3*%281-t%29*t%5E2%2B70*t%5E3%2C+100*3*%281-t%29%5E2*t%2B150*3*%281-t%29*t%5E2%29+t+from+0+to+1) or Mathematica ([which is free if you own a Raspberri PI](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi)): set up a random curve, and make them compute the length "properly", then use that result as reference value in your unit tests.

Comment: Unfortunately I bought my kids Arduinos not Raspberry PIs.   I've included a minimal example of calling your js code in my question as the answer.  I couldn't get Wolfram Alpha to give me an answer though.  I tried things like "arc-length of BezierFunction[{{4,4}, {4,12}, {16,12}, {16,4}}] between 0 and 1", using length arclength, the BezierCurve method and trying to integrate the sqrt of the distances for the cubic - hoping it would do something clever (a week ago now so hazy on the details).   I really should learn how to use these tools better.

Comment: yeah, for reasons unknown to me, there is no baked in bezier function, so you end up having to write them out, [like so](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arc+length+of+%28+4%281-t%29^3%2B3*4%281-t%29^2t+%2B+3*16%281-t%29t^2+%2B+16*t^3%2C+0%2C+4%281-t%29^3%2B3*12%281-t%29^2t+%2B+3*12%281-t%29t^2+%2B+4*t^3%29+for+t+from+0+to+1), also, given the $35 cost of a Raspberry Pi, I bought one specifically for Mathematica, which is $300 for home use, otherwise =P

Comment: Alright I'm sold.  I'll get one the next time one of my children's birthdays come around.  Hope you are on a commission :)

Comment: Yeah with your cubic you have to solve for the coefficients manually from the points.  Is that right?  Down side to that is I'd have to manually calculate the coefficients (which I do in code) and if I have a broken understanding of how that's done then I'll likely replicate the same broken logic calculating the coefficients manually that my code does.  So I suspect using your js libs is better for this particular application.  That said, now I know how to do it.  Which is nice cause now I've learnt something new.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: not anymore, thanks for heads up.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following to unit test your codes:

1) Split the Bezier curve into multiple Bezier curves using De Casteljau algorithm
2) compute the arc length for each of these Bezier curves then compute the sum of them.
3) compute the arc length for original Bezier curve.
4) compare the result from step 2 and 3. They should only differ by a very small numeric error if your codes is correct.

Another way to verify the arc length is to check if it is always between the two values computed below:

1) sample some points (let's say 100) from the Bezier curve and compute the polygon's length from the sampled points. This value will always be smaller than the actual arc length of the curve. 
2) compute the length of the control polygon. This will always be greater than the actual arc length of the curve.

Comment: you forgot 3) in the 2nd group: split your curve up into many smaller ones as in 1) above, and compute the sum of their control polygons' lengths. and yeah, very clever approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can get some values by fiddling around with the js widgets on this page
http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arclengthapprox

Comment: JS is most definitely not applets. They're just interactive HTML canvas. And I wouldn't give this link, go with the actual arc length computation as described in the section above it.

Comment: JS isn't .. but the little graphs you have on your bezier primer site, I would argue, are.   From wiki "an applet is any small application that performs one specific task that runs within the scope of a dedicated widget engine or a larger program, often as a plug-in".  They're certainly not java applets.  I could have picked a less overloaded term for them I guess.

Comment: applets, on the web, really are just java. These are interactive graphics without any kind of application engine running behind them: it's just JS =)

Comment: I'll change it from applets to widgets to save further argument :)

Answer (score 1):

Realise this is an old question but another solution is to use an SVG path element and the `getTotalLength` method. No libraries or complex equations required, let the browser do the heavy lifting.

In its simplest form:

```
var a = {x: 0, y: 0},  // from
    b = {x: 4, y: 4},  // to
    c1 = {x: 2, y: 0}, // curve 1
    c2 = {x: 2, y: 4}, // curve 2

    // output the curve in SVG bezier syntax
    svgBezier = `M${a.x} ${a.y} C ${c1.x} ${c1.y}, ${c2.x} ${c2.y}, ${b.x} ${b.y}`,

    // create a new <path> element
    path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");

// add the curve
path.setAttribute('d', svgBezier);

// get the length using browser power
console.log(path.getTotalLength());  // 5.981128692626953
```

Note: the above returns reliable results in chrome and safari .. firefox seems less reliable out of the box