# Cubic bezier curve arc length is always zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, bezier

I've written the following code to calculate the length of a cubic bezier curve. I got the idea from [Calculate the arclength, curve length of a cubic bezier curve. Why is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489520/calculate-the-arclength-curve-length-of-a-cubic-bezier-curve-why-is-not-workin). The problem is it always produces a length of zero.

```
public Vector2 SegmentAtPoint(int segmentIndex, float t)
{
    t = Mathf.Clamp01(t);
    float oneMinusT = 1f - t;

    return
        oneMinusT * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * points[segmentIndex * 3] + 
        3f * oneMinusT * oneMinusT * t * points[segmentIndex * 3 + 1] +
        3f * oneMinusT * t * t * points[segmentIndex * 3 + 2] +
        t * t * t * points[segmentIndex * 3 + 3];

}

public float SegmentLength(int segmentIndex)    {
    var steps = 10;
    var t = 1 / steps;
    var sumArc = 0.0f;
    var j = 0.0f;
    var a = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    var b = points[segmentIndex * 3];

    var dX = 0.0f;
    var dY = 0.0f;
    var dS = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < steps; j = j + t)
    {
        a = SegmentAtPoint(segmentIndex, j);

        dX = a.x - b.x;
        dY = a.y - b.y;
        dS = Mathf.Sqrt((dX * dX) + (dY * dY));

        sumArc = sumArc + dS;
        b.x = a.x;
        b.y = a.y;
        i++;
    }

    return sumArc;

}
```

Comment: My first guess would be that SegmentAtPoint returns a point that is the same or very close to b. Did you test this?

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/introduction/) already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code `var t = 1 / steps;` makes [integer division,](https://answers.unity.com/questions/411373/why-is-this-divide-calculation-returning-me-0.html) so result `t` is zero

Also note that `j = j + t` is executed **after** every loop, so at the first iteration `j==0`

This flaw causes such problem: both `b` and `a` are equal at the first iteration because `j` still remains =0. So you calculate segment lengths on intervals: `0-0, 0-0.1, 0.1-0.2...0.7-0.8,0.8-0.9` - ignoring `0.9-1.0` interval

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought `var j = 0.0f;` before the loop caters for the second part of your solution. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No. I added explanation